Pusher Authentication Endpoint Not Found in Angular Service
I am working on an Angular 18 application that integrates with a Laravel 10 backend for real-time features using Pusher. However, I'm encountering a 404 error when my Angular application tries to authenticate with Pusher.
Error:
POST http://localhost:4200/pusher/auth 404 (Not Found)
Angular Service Code (stream.service.ts):
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StreamService {
  private echo: Echo;
  private apiBaseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: 'pusher',
      key: '****',
      cluster: 'eu',
      client: new Pusher('***', {
        cluster: 'eu',
        forceTLS: true
      }),
      authEndpoint: `${this.apiBaseUrl}/pusher/auth`,
      auth: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}`
        }
      },
      forceTLS: true,
    });
  }

  startStream() {
    return this.http.post<{ stream_id: string }>(`${this.apiBaseUrl}/stream/start`, {});
  }

  joinStream(streamId: string) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiBaseUrl}/stream/join/${streamId}`, {});
  }

  leaveStream(streamId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiBaseUrl}/stream/leave/${streamId}`, {});
  }

  listenToStream(streamId: string, callback: (user: any) => void) {
    this.echo.join(`stream.${streamId}`)
      .here((users) => {
        console.log('Users in stream:', users);
      })
      .joining((user) => {
        console.log(user.name + ' joined the stream.');
        callback(user);
      })
      .leaving((user) => {
        console.log(user.name + ' left the stream.');
      });
  }
}

Laravel Routes (api.php):
Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {
    Route::post('/stream/start', [StreamController::class, 'startStream']);
    Route::post('/stream/join/{streamId}', [StreamController::class, 'joinStream']);
});

Route::post('/pusher/auth', [StreamController::class, 'authBroadcast']);

Laravel Broadcast Configuration (broadcasting.php):
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),
    'connections' => [
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http',
                'encrypted' => false,
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ],
            ],
            'auth' => [
                'endpoint' => '/api/pusher/auth',
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . env('JWT_TOKEN'),
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

Laravel Channels Configuration (channels.php):
<?php

Broadcast::channel('stream.{streamId}', function ($user) {
    return ['id' => $user->id, 'name' => $user->name];
});

and .env
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=***
PUSHER_APP_KEY=****
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=***
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=eu

Laravel Broadcast Service Provider (BroadcastServiceProvider.php):
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\ExampleEvent' => [
            'App\Listeners\ExampleListener',
        ],
    ];
    
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['api']]);
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}

